# Error when using static libraries in Android NDK

Tags: android, c, static-libraries, cross-compiling, android-ndk

I got this error when trying to use a static library:

```
/home/user/android-ndk-r5b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: 
skipping incompatible /home/user/android-ndk-r5b/apps/HelloNDK/obj/local/armeabi/libtest.a when searching for -ltest
```

In what may be the problem? Thanks in advance

UPDATE:
To compile I've done this:

```
PREBUILT=/home/user/android-ndk/build/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-eabi-4.4.0
PLATFORM=/home/user/android-ndk/build/platforms/android-3/arch-arm
INSTALL=/home/user/test-14.3.2/com5

./configure --build=arm \
    --prefix=$INSTALL \

  --with-flac=dyn \

--enable-static \



    CC=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-eabi-gcc \
    CFLAGS="-fPIC -DANDROID" \
    LDFLAGS="-Wl,-T,$PREBUILT/arm-eabi/lib/ldscripts/armelf.x -Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -nostdlib $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.0/crtbegin.o $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.0/crtend.o -lc -lm -ldl"
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got an hint from the linker : the library seems to be found, but skipped as incorrect.

Are you sure you compiled your library with the same compiler ? If it's compiled for another platform / with another compiler, you'll have an ABI issue and the linker will discard the lib, which it seems to do.

Comment: I'm not sure. I compile with gcc under Linux (with - build = arm) and did make and make install. How can you do? If so then what could be my fault? (after receiving the file. a - threw it in a folder in the Android project, obj)

Comment: You should use the ndk to compile your library as well, using standrd gcc with -build=arm is not enough (for example, rtti)

Comment: After this script I do make and make install. Is that true? What could be the problem?

Comment: So what? Answer? Thanks in advance

Comment: No clue here, can't help more